# Multiple shell commands in applescript - how to ask for password only once?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, sudo

I have a script to set routes to the routing table and open an application. It works fine and does the job.

The challenge is that some of the commands need **sudo** privileges and thus when I run the script I am asked to enter my password multiple times. How can I make the script ask only once for the password? See an excerpt of the code here:

```
-- delete current routes and store output in variable
set del1 to do shell script "sudo route delete " & MyURL_IP
set del2 to do shell script "sudo route delete " & MyURL_IP2
beep -- one beep for deleting the routes first

-- add new routes to table and store output in variable
set add1 to do shell script "sudo route -nv add " & MyURL_IP & " " & IPAdrGatway & "| grep 'add host'"
set add2 to do shell script "sudo route -nv add " & MyURL_IP2 & " " & IPAdrGatway & "| grep 'add host'"
beep -- one beep for adding new routes

-- create and write to logfile on desktop with timestamp
set the logFile to ((path to desktop) as text) & "RouteAirmail.log.txt"
try
    open for access file the logFile with write permission
    write (return & (current date) & return) to file the logFile starting at eof
    write (del1 & return & del2 & return & add1 & return & add2 & return) to file the logFile starting at eof
    close access file the logFile
on error
    try
        close access file the logFile
    end try
end try
```

Those commands require to enter the pwd:

1. password request when deleting existing routes
2. when adding routes
3. when writing to log file

I have tried different options, e.g. run everything as a shell script, but seems not so elegant to me.

Comment: Apple has some documentation on shell scripts within applescript, including around administrator privileges: [Technical Note TN2065: do shell script in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG1-HOW_DO_I_GET_ADMINISTRATOR_PRIVILEGES_FOR_A_COMMAND_). A single script should retain privileges for five minutes but each script will require authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Remove « sudo » and use

do shell script "command" user name "username" password "pass" with administrator privileges

Comment: Good point! I like "with administrator privileges" and I did not know that there is a difference in that (vs. using sudo command).

But for security reasons I did not add the user, nor the password and instead of insisting to put at least the pwd once. I think that is better and I use TouchID so it wont bother me too much. 

Thanks a lot for the hint!